# C# run serial port data received event handler to another form

Tags: c#

In my form1 I have serialPort1 and I want to run the serialPort1_DataRecieved to another form.
or create the datarecieved handler to the form2 using form1 serialport.

I am passing my serial port to another form using this code.

```
 FOrm1 f1= new Form1(serialPort1);
 f1.Show();
```

this is what i want trying to do in my Form2

```
    SerialPort serialPort2;
    public delegate void myDelegate(string sData);
    public Form2(SerialPort SP)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serialPort2 = SP;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort2.Open();
            serialPort2.DataReceived += port_OnReceiveData;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
   publicstatic void port_OnReceiveData(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        string sData;
        serialPort2.ReadTimeout = 20;

        try
        {
            sData = serialPort2.ReadLine();
            this.BeginInvoke((new myDelegate(Text_Out)), sData);
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
```

i solve my problem doing this

Comment: Separate business from ui layers. Have your serialPort Data be stored in a common datastore, maybe fire events on new data, then you can register and request data from any forms you like.

Comment: can i use that serialPort2 to do the datarecieved handler and run it into that form?

Comment: can u get me some possible solution to doing that?

Comment: You can only connect one instance to a serialport at the same time. If you try opening a second connection, it will fail telling you it is already in use.

Answer (score 0):

do like this: simply create interface on form 2 then inherit it in form one and set form one to interface of the form 2, after that call the methods in interface from form2,form 2

```
  public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public interface ABC
        {
             void OK(string data);
        }

        public ABC abc { get; set; } 

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            abc.OK("hi");
        }
    }
```

in your form 1

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form,ABC
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f = new Form2();
            f.abc = this;
            f.Show();

        }

        public void OK(string data)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i want is to run the datarecieved event handler using serialport in another form

Comment: yes you can run. lets assume   datarecieved   call back in your form 2. in my example there is a  abc.OK("hi"); method call in form2 with arguments in onclick method.( you can call it on your datarecieved call back.) it will instantly call the ok method in form one with you provided arguments from form 2

Comment: your are passing string in OK method? but why? i dont need to pass a String.. how can i call the datarecieved event in here?

Comment: i think you want to call form one's method with arguments from form2. am I correct?

Comment: yes i get my solution see updated question above but my problem now i cannot close or dispose the serialport

Comment: you mean you want to close the serial port after triggering the event?

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem doing this

```
    SerialPort serialPort2;
    public delegate void myDelegate(string sData);
    public Form2(SerialPort SP)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serialPort2 = SP;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort2.Open();
            serialPort2.DataReceived += port_OnReceiveData;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
   publicstatic void port_OnReceiveData(object sender, 
   System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        string sData;
        serialPort2.ReadTimeout = 20;

        try
        {
            sData = serialPort2.ReadLine();
            this.BeginInvoke((new myDelegate(Text_Out)), sData);
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
```

Comment: oh great. you asked how how bind events. i missed understand your question.